# Scala Value class takes more memory than expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of my program and want to use scala's `Value class` in order to define a variable which acts like java `primitive type` as explained [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

My definition of the class is:

```
class userhashVal(val data: Int) extends AnyVal with Serializable
```

it uses the serializable trait which has the following signature:

```
trait Serializable extends scala.Any with java.io.Serializable
```

So it is compatible with the demands specified in the link (traits are allowed only to extend universal traits). I must add the Serializable trait in order to make it compatible with Spark.

What I expect is that the each `userhashVal` element will take only 4 bytes as Java's int. but using a profiler I get the following picture:

[image]

Where I see the memory this elemtn occupies is 20 bytes and I understand it still acts as a class since it has a classloader.

What am I missing here? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you use a value class, the class gets swapped with the underlying primitive. Why do you need it to extend serializable?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want to use it with Spark so it must be serializable.

Comment: According to the documentation, [scala sometimes needs to actually instantiate a value class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#when-allocation-is-necessary). There's not much more to say without seeing the code which actually creates the `userhashVal` instance. Also, it would be worth decompiling it with `javap`.

Comment: But `int` is serializable. How are you using this code?

Comment: You are probably passing it to some method that expects a `Serializable`. Treating a value class as another type is one of the things that causes the class to be instantiated.

Comment: @Jasper-M this makes sense, before I added the `with Serializable` Spark failed with error specifying userhashVal is not serializable.

Comment: You can try using a tagged type instead (http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html), they can avoid instantiation in some circumstances where value classes don't (though not always).